# Use box java sdk to download an item without knowing if it's a file or a folder

Tags: java, box-api, box

With the ID of an item stored on box, you can download it if it's a file, or download its contents if it's a folder. Either way it seems you need to know what sort of thing you're downloading in order to access it, doing either `BoxFile file = new BoxFile(api, id);` or `BoxFolder folder = new BoxFolder(api, id);` before handling the actual download.

I was hoping to be able to do something like

```
BoxItem boxItem = new BoxItem(api, id);
if (boxItem instanceof BoxFile) {
    // download file
} else if (boxItem instanceof BoxFolder) {
    // download all files in folder
}
```

sort of like [the example in the docs of downloading a folder's contents](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk/blob/master/doc/folders.md#get-a-folders-items). However, in that case the ID is that of a specific folder, whereas my ID is for either a folder or a file in the root folder, and I don't want to loop through all of the root folder's contents. And, anyway, `BoxItem` cannot be instantiated.

How can I tell ahead of time whether I'm downloading a file or a folder, with just the item's ID? If not, is there a way to download the item anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe the API supports downloading an entire folder (and therefore the SDK doesn't either). The closest you can get is downloading all of the folder's files. That's why `BoxFile` has a `download()` method, but `BoxFolder` and `BoxItem` don't.

As for checking whether or not an ID corresponds to a file or folder - there isn't a way to tell without trying to make an API request. For example, you could try doing `new BoxFile(api, id).getInfo()` and seeing if it returns a 404.